# OAuth 2.0 WebServer separated from the API Webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth

I'm asking if it is possible to build a central WebServer in .NET CORE that uses Oauth2.0 protocol for generating tokens that client needs in other to perform a request to my custom APIs that resides in another webserver. I mean, for example, a client login in the Oauth 2.0 central web server, retrieves the access token and then use this token with my servers. I also need that the database in the OAuth 2.0 webserver is customizable for saving my users' data.

I saw IdentityServer 4, but from what I have understood from this library is that it lives in the same server where I built my custom API, and I need this to be an external entity that creates token for my clients and my API uses this token to verify the users identity.

Have I misunderstood IdentityServer 4, or it possible to do this with it? If not possible, someone have any idea about already made technologies that may perform what I want to do?

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: You have misunderstood IdentityServer. It can run on the same app as the API or it can run in a different app/server. It's a token service.

Comment: Ok thanks, is there a guide that teach me how to make IdentityServer4 works as autonomous webserver in net core?

Comment: Here is one at least: https://github.com/BenjaminAbt/Samples.AspNetCore-IdentityServer4.

Comment: The best place is the IdentityServer4 docs. The documentation is actually pretty good as far as things go, and there's lots of sample code in linked repos.